# Passing an intent via JSONObject in Android

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I have the following code:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("message", message);
obj.put("flag", flag);
obj.put("intent", intent);
arr.put(obj);
Utility.saveDataLocally(getApplicationContext(), Constants.SOME_CONST, arr.toString());
```

where `intent` is an object of `Intent` class. Now, after saving this JSONArray in Utility, I want to retrieve this saved JSONArray from another activity, so I am doing the following for the same:

```
String s = Utility.getSaveDataLocally(this, Constants.SOME_CONST);
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(s);
//Below works
String m = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("message");
//But below doesn't (obviously).
Intent i = arr.getJSONObject(0).getIntent("intent");
```

Can you please tell me how do I achieve the above? That is, passing an intent via a JSONObject, in Android, and receiving it correctly from the other end?

Comment: why do you want to pass it as a json array?

Comment: I'm creating a Notifications Page where a list of received gcm notifications would be shown. Hence I am storing the last 10 gcm notifications as a JSONArray in Utility, so that I can simply read from them and show in the page. Problem is, I need to pass the intent as well, to handle which activity should be opened on tapping on which notification from that page.

Comment: Create a model class with "msg","flag","intent" fields. 
1. Use Gson lib to convert model class data to string data.
2 . Pass as as string.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make an **`arrayList of hash-map`** and in that put the page name as a key value pair.So that way you also can navigate to that page along with the data,Try this and it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : create POJO class for Notification (lets say) 
Which is parcelable.. hence you can parse this class object from one activity to other

```
public class Notification implements Parcelable {
/**
 * message : you have successfully registered
 * flag : 0
 * intent : incoming msg
 */

private String message;
private int flag;
private String intent;

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void setFlag(int flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

public void setIntent(String intent) {
    this.intent = intent;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public int getFlag() {
    return flag;
}

public String getIntent() {
    return intent;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.message);
    dest.writeInt(this.flag);
    dest.writeString(this.intent);
}

public Notification() {
}

protected Notification(Parcel in) {
    this.message = in.readString();
    this.flag = in.readInt();
    this.intent = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Notification> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Notification>() {
    public Notification createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Notification(source);
    }

    public Notification[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Notification[size];
    }
};
}
```

step 2 : first activity code .. here we are using GSON library from google (to serialize or deserialize the json object to java object)

```
private static final String NOTIFICATIONS="NOTIFICATIONS";
try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("message", "you have successfully registered");
        obj.put("flag", 0);
        obj.put("intent", "incoming msg");

        Gson gson=new Gson();
        ArrayList<Notification> notificationList=new ArrayList<>();
        Notification notification=gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Notification.class);
        notificationList.add(notification);

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(NOTIFICATIONS, notificationList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (JSONException je)
    {
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
```

step 2 : second activity code to get parcelable data for notification

```
private static final String NOTIFICATIONS="NOTIFICATIONS";
ArrayList<Notification> notifications=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(NOTIFICATIONS);
    for(Notification notification: notifications)
    {
        Log.d("NOTIFICATIONS", "Message = "+notification.getMessage());
        Log.d("NOTIFICATIONS", "Flag = "+notification.getFlag());
        Log.d("NOTIFICATIONS", "Intent = "+notification.getIntent());
        Log.d("NOTIFICATIONS", "");
    }
```